# Connecting two Arduino Mkr WiFis

Tags: server, arduino, client, wifi, arduino-c++

I want to connect Arduino WiFis via WiFi. As Server I'm using a UNO WiFi Rev2 and two Mkr 1010 as Clients (I know it doesn't matter which one is server and which is client).

As server I'm using the standard Arduino AP-programm similar to this:
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFi101BeginAP

As client I'm using the standard Arduino client programm:
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFiClient

Both are working, the server is accessable from a PC, the client connects to a WiFi network.

Problem:
The Arduino client doesn't connect to the Arduino server and I don't understand why. The client simply tries to connect to the network but can't build a stable connection.

Comment: please read [ask]. you should provide your code as a [mcve]

Comment: The code is provided in the links above.

Comment: explain " The client simply tries to connect to the network but can't build a stable connection." and " the client connects to a WiFi network"

Comment: The Arduino connects to a standard WiFi network but not to a network hosted by another Arduino.

Comment: the examples don't start the AP on the Arduino. they expect the Arduinos are connected to the same network. this are examples of TCP communication which has nothing to do with the physical WiFi network.

Comment: I am very sorry, I pasted in the wrong link. I used the WiFi101 AP program as a server.
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFi101BeginAP

Comment: you should use the examples of the WiFiNINA library. create the AP with password

Comment: Where is the difference between the WiFi101 and NINA programm? Both examples look like they have the excact same structure.

Comment: try AP with password